# Mostrar errores Ajax devueltos desde PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy teniendo problemas para mostrar un error personalizado en una respuesta php enviada por ajax.

Supongamos esta llamada Ajax:

```
var uri = "http://localhost/aniadir.php"
        $.ajax({
            url: uri,
            data: data,
            method: "POST",
            dataType:"json",
            async: true,

            success: function (response) {

                console.log("OK" + response.data.message);



            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {

                console.log("ERROR" + errorMessage + textStatus + xhr);

            }
        }); // end ajax
```

Desde PHP fuerzo un error en la conexión a la BD:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'error', 'tabla');

$jsondata["success"] = false;
$jsondata["data"] = array(
   'message' => $mysqli->error     
);

 header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
 echo json_encode($jsondata, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Si la respuesta es success, el mensaje se muestra correctamente mediante response.data.message

El problema es cómo mostrar el mensaje creado en PHP cuando es un error.

Answer (score 1):

La cuestión es que no estás informando de un error HTTP. Para el JS, es una petición que ha sido respondida de forma correcta.

Sí, en el JSON pones un campo "success" a falso, pero eso no es lo que controla el JS. El JS mira el HTTP Response Code; si el PHP termina con normalidad (no excepción) devolverá 200 y para el JS el mensaje no será de error.

Lo que tienes que hacer para que JS invoque al *handler* de error es devolver un HTTP Response Code de error, en este caso lo más normal sería 500 (Internal Server Error).

Puedes usar la función [http-response-code](http://php.net/manual/es/function.http-response-code.php).

Comment: Si pongo datos erroneos  de conexión a la BD el codigo de response es 200 y entra en caso de error de la llamada Ajax.  Segun lo que comentas debería entrar en el caso de success..

Comment: Lo que necesito es para una respuesta de codigo 200 mostrar un mensaje de error personalizado desde el caso error en ajax

Answer (score 1):

te recomiendo que a la hora de hacer la peticion con ayax estes mirando la consola del navegador,en el apartado de Red,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si es posible selecciona la opcion de mantener los registros, cuando hagas la peticion veras que se genera otro registro.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo dicho, cuando generes la petición lo podrás ver, si das un click sobre la petición podrá ver la respuesta de esta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te recomiendo trabajar más con devtools de tu navegador, te será muy útil para la programación Web

Suerte!!